# How to parse HTML getting the text from H1 ... H6?

Tags: html, ruby, nokogiri

I want to parse an HTML page, and I only want to get all the text inside `<h1>` .. `<h6>` tags.

My actual script is:

```
doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open(s3_page_url).read)
doc.css('h1, h2').each do |link|
  puts link.text
end
```

Here's my test code:

```
html = '<html><head><title><h1>foo</h1><h2>bar</h2></title><body><p>bar</p></body></html>'
doc = Nokogiri::HTML(html)
doc.css('h1').each do |link|
  puts link.text
end
```

And here's the prompt:

```
foo
```

The thing is that I want to get `foo bar`.

Comment: what's problem with your code... ? Your approach is correct, I can see.

Comment: Edited my post. Please read again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`#map`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Enumerable.html#method-i-map) to get an array of text first.Then [`#join`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Array.html#method-i-join) to construct an *string* with your choice of *delimiter* .

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

require 'nokogiri'

html = <<-STRING
<html><head><title><h1>foo</h1><h2>bar</h2></title><body><p>bar</p></body></html>
STRING

doc = Nokogiri::HTML::DocumentFragment.parse(html)


doc.css('h1, h2').map(&:text).join(" ") # => "foo bar"
```

Comment: Ok now the thing is that I want to read an URL and then parse it with nokogiri(instead of taking from html var I want to read from and URL that I've got from amazon s3)